# Could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known - DOCKER

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a dash app and i'm trying to host it to the port 8050 so i'm trying to create it using gunicorn and I ran my Dockerfile which contains:

```
FROM airflow-update
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8050 /py_scripts.index:server
```

and then i ran

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 airflow
```

and i got the error below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
```

My docker-compose.yaml file is like this:

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-airflow:latest}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs/pipeline-logs
    - ./py_scripts:/opt/airflow/py_scripts
    - ./data:/opt/airflow/data
    - ./dbt-redshift:/opt/airflow/dbt-redshift
    - ./output:/opt/airflow/output  
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

What am i doing wrong. Should i update my docker-compose file in regards to postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Compose creates a network named `default`, but your `docker run` command isn't attached to that network.

The best approach to this is to move this setup inside your Compose setup.  If the only thing you're replacing is the command that's being run, you don't even need a custom image.  This is the same pattern you have for the several other containers in this setup.

```yaml
services:
  postgres: { ... }
  airflow-server:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8050 /py_scripts.index:server
    ports:
      - '8050:8050'
    restart: always
```

If you really want to run it with `docker run`, you need to find the network Compose creates by default and specifically attach to it.  `docker network ls` will show it; its name will end with `..._default`.  Note that there's a huge amount of additional setup in the `airflow-common` block and `docker run` won't see any of this at all.

```bash
docker run --net airflow_default -p 8050:8050 airflow
```

Comment: I tried your approach but now my airflow-server container shows this error when it runs
 

    **airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'gunicorn' 
    (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dags', 'db', 'info', 'jobs', ' 
    kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 
    'scheduler', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adjusting @davidmaze's answer as below:

```
  airflow-server:
    <<: *airflow-common
    ports:
      - '8050:8050'
    restart: always
    entrypoint: gunicorn --chdir /opt/airflow/py_scripts -b 0.0.0.0:8050 index:server
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).